# quickbooks desktop enterprise integration with mulesoft

Tags: mule, desktop-application, quickbooks, enterprise

I have to build a integration between Mulesoft and QuickBooks Desktop Enterprise edition. How Can the same be done? I know that for QuickBooks Online, as soon as access code is generated, a web service call will do whatever functionality is required. Is the same possible for Desktop enterprise also? If yes, please give some sample. I have to create Bills in QuickBooks enterprise using this integration.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a [connector](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.modules/mule-module-quick-books-windows/) for that.

Comment: It says it is a desktop connector, but it actually is a windows connector. I am not sure if this is the same thing. Any idea on that?

Comment: What do you mean by `windows connector`?